# Five people are seared in a circle and there are hats of 3 colours which are to be distributed among them.

Tags: permutations, combinations

Five persons A,B,C,D and E are seated in a circular arrangement. If each of them is given a hat of one of the three colours red, blue and green, then the number of ways of distributing the hats such that the persons seated in adjacent seats get different coloured hats is__

I wanted to ask why the question cannot be solved in the following manner:

1. Select 1 of 5 people by 5C1 ways and give them one of 3 hats in 3C1 way.
2. There are 2 choices for the adjacent person so 2C1
3. There are again 2 choices for the next adjacent person so 2C1
4. There are again 2 choices for the next adjacent person so 2C1
5. The last person has only 1 choice so 1C1

Which gives us 120 but the answer is 30.

I am aware of the solution of the problem, but I want to know why this method doesn't work.

Comment: A coloring counted by a choice of one person as the first one analyzed is also counted by the same process, when a person next to them was the choice as the first person in the analysis.

Comment: multiplying by $5$ is the first mistake. You can start with any person. If you take that out, you have undercounting. If first and fourth person have the same color hat, the fifth has two choices.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are arranged in a circle, there are symmetries that reduce the number of combinations. When you use the choose function, it marks one of the people as "first" in your counting. But due to the fact that you can rotate the arrangement without changing the actual hat distribution means that you actually have fewer arrangements than you get at first.

For this problem specifically, there are 5 ways to orient the circle (think about the sides of a pentagon and how you can rotate the top point onto the 4 others). So you need to divide by 4 to account for the extra arrangements.